# AngularJS - Use id from collection like id in div tag and like function parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Hey :) I'm using AngularJS's directive ngRepeat because I need list of all items from my collection.
But problem is that I want my list items are accordions which opens when I click on list item.

HTML :

```
<div class="w3-accordion w3-light-grey" style="width: 70%; margin: auto">
    <div ng-repeat="question in questions">
        <button ng-click="myFunction('{{ question._id }}')" class="w3-btn-block w3-left-align">
            {{ question.question }}</button>
        <div id="{{ question._id }}" class="w3-accordion-content w3-container">
            {{ question.answers }}
            {{ question.rightAnswer }}
            {{ question.points }}
        </div>
    </div>      
</div>
```

As you can see I want list of questions and I want to open accordion one by one by id and it's item should be some question attributes.

Here is function which should be doin' it.

JS :

```
function myFunction(id) {
var x = document.getElementById(id);
    if (x.className.indexOf("w3-show") == -1) {
        x.className += " w3-show";
    } else {
         x.className = x.className.replace(" w3-show", "");
    }
}
```

The problem is because the function isn't called at all (I think so).

If you can help me I would be very very grateful :)

Comment: You should put ng-click="myFunction(question._id)", angular evaluates it for you and then passes the correct id into the function

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work

Comment: Have you set the myFunction to be on your scope? $scope.myFunction = myFunction;

Comment: No I haven't :O what lapse!!!!
Thank you :D now is working

Comment: Do yourself a favor and get rid of jQuery entirely.  It will help you to learn how to use angular more properly.  Performing manual DOM manipulation (or evaluation), with jQuery in this case, while using angular means you don't really understand what angular is for ... you are just using a small piece of it.  I am not trying to be rude, we all learn by doing.

Comment: Thank you for advice. You're right :) I'm still learnin'

Answer (score 1):

Don't use expression syntax as an function argument, so just change:

```
ng-click="myFunction('{{ question._id }}')"
```

to

```
ng-click="myFunction(question._id)"
```

Hope I helped :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see comments above